# R: Leaving out undefined columns when subsetting a dataframe

Tags: r, error-handling

I have a dataframe df1 with 300+ Columns, and I am trying to subset it to df2 by column names based on a couple dozen inputs in list1. However, some of the items in list1 are not actually column names in df1. So, I get an "undefined columns" error:

> df2 <- df1[,list1]
>   Error in `[.data.frame`(df1, , list1) :
>     undefined columns selected

I realize the reason for this error. BUT I can't go through list1 and see which ones occur in df1 and which ones don't. Because I have to do this many many times with many many different lists. Is there a way to simply ignore those (and not include those null column name values from list1 in the subset df2)?

Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like: `df2 <- df1[,list1[list1 %in% names(df1)]]`

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping for a nicer/shorter) solution for my own use. 
Here is another

```
df1[,intersect(names(df1), list1)]
```